# SQL Server SUM then MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, max, ssms

How can I get the MAX value for the SUM range that I have?

Current output:

```
Size  |  Format | ColB   | Value
Large |  PCT    | Tmp1   | 23.05
Large |  PCT    | Tmp3   | 109.00
Large |  PCT    | Tmp50  | 3.22
Large |  PCT    | Tmp109 | 987.23
Large |  PCT    | Tmp58  | 455.30
```

Expected Output:

```
Size  |  Format | ColB   | Value  | Max_Value
Large |  PCT    | Tmp1   | 23.05  | 987.23
Large |  PCT    | Tmp3   | 109.00 | 987.23
Large |  PCT    | Tmp50  | 3.22   | 987.23
Large |  PCT    | Tmp109 | 987.23 | 987.23
Large |  PCT    | Tmp58  | 455.30 | 987.23
```

Let me know if this is possible.

Current code below:

```
USE DB1

DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE
DECLARE @ColA VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @ColB VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @ColC VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @ColD VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @ColE VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @ColF VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @ColG VARCHAR(15)

BEGIN
SET @StartDate = '01/01/2017'
SET @EndDate = '01/14/2017'
SET @ColA = '%%'
SET @ColB = '%%'
SET @ColC = '%%'
SET @ColD = '%%'
SET @ColE = '%%'
SET @ColF = '%%'
SET @ColG = '%%'
END

SELECT
    'Large' AS [Size]
    ,'PCT' AS [Format]
    ,[ColB]
    ,CAST((SUM([Numerator])/SUM([Denominator]))*100 AS NUMERIC(12,2)) AS [Value]
FROM [Table1] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND [ColA] LIKE @ColA
AND [ColB] LIKE @ColB
AND [ColC] LIKE @ColC
AND [ColD] LIKE @ColD
AND [ColE] LIKE @ColE
AND [ColF] LIKE @ColF
AND [ColG] LIKE @ColG
GROUP BY [ColB]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add an un-correlated sub-query to the select list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a window function like this:

```
SELECT
    'Large' AS [Size]
    ,'PCT' AS [Format]
    ,[ColB]
    ,CAST((SUM([Numerator])/SUM([Denominator]))*100 AS NUMERIC(12,2)) AS [Value]
    ,cast(max(sum([Numerator])/sum([Denominator])) over(partition by null)) as numeric(12,2)) *100 as [MaxValue]
FROM [Table1] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND [ColA] LIKE @ColA
AND [ColB] LIKE @ColB
AND [ColC] LIKE @ColC
AND [ColD] LIKE @ColD
AND [ColE] LIKE @ColE
AND [ColF] LIKE @ColF
AND [ColG] LIKE @ColG
GROUP BY [ColB]
```

I think it should work in your case.

Comment: This works as expected. Thank you. Additional question, how can I create a new column to return 'Yes' if the [Value] for that row matches the [MaxValue]? This is just for easier visibility, if this is not feasible, it is fine. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: You can wrap up this query in an outer query and do the check there:

`select a.*, iif(a.Value = a.MaxValue, 'YES', 'NO') as IfMatches
from (SELECT 'Large' AS [Size]
    ,'PCT' AS [Format]
    ,[ColB]
...
...
GROUP BY [ColB] ) as a`

Answer (score 1):

Use a Sub query of your `SUM` and then use the `MAX` function to get this.

```
SELECT 'Large' AS [Size], 'PCT' AS [Format], [ColB],
CAST((SUM([Numerator])/SUM([Denominator]))*100 AS NUMERIC(12,2)) AS [Value],
    (SELECT MAX(SUBValue) 
    FROM (SELECT [ColB], CAST((SUM([Numerator])/SUM([Denominator]))*100 AS NUMERIC(12,2)) AS [SUBValue]
         FROM [Table1] WITH(NOLOCK)
         WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
         AND [ColA] LIKE @ColA
         AND [ColB] LIKE @ColB
         AND [ColC] LIKE @ColC
         AND [ColD] LIKE @ColD
         AND [ColE] LIKE @ColE
         AND [ColF] LIKE @ColF
         AND [ColG] LIKE @ColG
         GROUP BY [ColB])) AS Max_Value
FROM [Table1] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND [ColA] LIKE @ColA
AND [ColB] LIKE @ColB
AND [ColC] LIKE @ColC
AND [ColD] LIKE @ColD
AND [ColE] LIKE @ColE
AND [ColF] LIKE @ColF
AND [ColG] LIKE @ColG
GROUP BY [ColB]
```